# How to move the scroll indicator of UITableView a little bit more to right?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there any way to move that scroll indicator to the right by some pixels?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See UIScrollView's `scrollIndicatorInsets` property. It can also be set in IB on Inspector's "Size" tab.

Comment: Also note that you can have negative values like I had to use for instance `UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, -3)`